# How can I elegantly print numeric strings as integers if they are whole?

Tags: perl, formatting

The idea here is to have numbers like `"12.0"` printed as `"12"`, but not change partial numbers like `"14.6"`.

For sure there are many ways to approach it, but the following just don't seem DWIM/elegant enough to me.

1. `s#\.0+$## for ( "12.0", "14.6" );`
2. `$_ = int($_)==$_ ? int($_) : $_ for ( "12.0", "14.6" );`

Comment: how about `say 0+$_ for @numbers`? Numifying the strings, then printing them will DWIM

Comment: @amon : Yeah, that works, had forgotten about that one. Wondering if there is a way to twist `sprintf` into submission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use that numbers are printed in a DWIM fashion:

```
say 0+$_ for @numbers;
```

Or if you want to use `sprintf` formats, you can use the `%g` pattern. This prints numbers like `%e` or `%f`. For small integers, `%e` behaves like `%d`.

```
printf "%g\n", $_ for "200000000.0", "12.0", "16.13";
```

Output:

```
2e+08
12
16.13
```

Comment: Yup, that's it. I knew it would be simple!

Answer (score 1):

```
my @array = map { $_ + 0 } ( "12.0", "14.6" );
```